# Hide characters after certain index with symbols

Tags: java

I understand that I did a lot of hard coding that can be avoided so if anything can share their thought please go ahead:

```
private String hideEmailCharacters(String privateEmail){
    String emailName = privateEmail.substring(0,privateEmail.indexOf("@"));
    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder(emailName);
    stringBuffer.replace(emailName.length() / 2,emailName.length(), StringUtils.repeat("*", emailName.length() / 2));
    String emailProvider = privateEmail.substring(privateEmail.indexOf("@"));
    return stringBuffer + emailProvider;
}
```

1. The goal is to cover for example half of the email name or cover everything after the second character with stars **  so the result from abcdv@example.com would be ab***@example.com

Comment: What is your question? Does the code you've written work? If so and you just want someone's opinion on it, it's off-topic for StackOverflow. You can post it to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. If it doesn't work, you need to tell us in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: I found a case which doesn't work `hideEmailCharacters("a@foo.com")` -> `@foo.com` I guess it should be either `*@foo.com` or unchanged

Comment: @Michael good catch man thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String processing is cool but here's a solution with **Regular Expression.**

```
(?<=.{2}).(?=[^@]*?@)
```

#### Intuition:

- Ignore first 2 characters from the characters before @
- Ignore @ as well.
- Replace each character between with `*`

```
public class TestCode {
    private static String hideEmailCharacters(String privateEmail) {
        return privateEmail.replaceAll("(?<=.{2}).(?=[^@]*?@)", "*");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(hideEmailCharacters("abcdv@example.com"));
        System.out.println(hideEmailCharacters("ra0o29ajzsdc242@example.com"));
        System.out.println(hideEmailCharacters("x2helloyouthere@example.com"));
        System.out.println(hideEmailCharacters("a@foo.com"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
ab***@example.com
ra*************@example.com
x2*************@example.com
a@foo.com
```

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code will do the trick:

```
StringBuffer email = new StringBuffer(privateEmail)
int startIndex = email.indexOf("@")/2;
int endIndex = email.indexOf("@");
int numOfCharsToHide = endIndex - startIndex;
email.replace(startIndex, endIndex, "*".repeat(numOfCharsToHide));
```